Consistency of directions in physics
I'm having a lot of trouble maintaining consistency with directions in physics and would like to demonstrate this with a problem. I hope for an answer that does not just resolve the problem but clarifies the general issue of maintaining consistent directions (so no, I am not just asking for homework help).

My approach here is to start with the reference height $0$ at the very bottom and then change the reference height to the height of the spring. I want to do this by subtracting out the spring's height once I create the equation.
Attached is a diagram demonstrating this:

Defined are the height of the spring, $h_s$, the height of the block (relative to the surface) $h_b$, $h_F$, the final height of the block at max compression of the string, and $x_b$, the compression distance of the spring.
The compression distance of the spring, denoted as $ x_B $, is defined as the difference between the initial height $ h_s $ and the final height $ h_F $:
$$x_B = h_s - h_F.$$
The first equation:

The first equation:
$$
mg(h_s + h_B) = \int\limits_{h_s}^{h_F} 105 \, x^{2.5} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \cos(180^\circ) + mg h_F
$$

After subtracting ($h_s$):
$$mgh_B = \int\limits_{0}^{h_F - h_s} 105 \, x^{2.5} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \cos(180^\circ) + mg(h_F - h_s)$$

In the final equation:
$$mgh_B = \int\limits_{0}^{-h_B} 105 \, x^{2.5} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \cos(180^\circ) + mg(-x_B).$$


However, plugging this into my calculator gives an invalid answer. I get the correct answer when I remove the $\cos(180^\circ)$, though, but I don't understand why. Isn't the block going opposite the direction of the force?
Finally, what is a strategy for dealing with directions in physics? I seem to always mess them up/be inconsistent, and from class lectures/practice assignments, it almost feels subjective/speculatory what directions things are. I want to find a way to define one consistent axis and apply it, but so far, that isn't working (the problem is an example). I can't seem to understand why, and I would like your help understanding this.
This is beyond a homework answer, and any answers here can help people understand how directions work in physics and how to correctly define axes, baselines, and coordinates.

I realized my mistake with this one. I forgot that U = -W, and so I forgot a negative sign. However, I would appreciate it if I could get some tips on managing directions in physics.

Directions aren’t physical. You get to choose any coordinate system you like. Normally you choose one that makes the math as simple as possible. And you have to be consistent in whatever you do.

Thanks! What are some tips for being consistent with directions? Apologies if this is a vague question
